# Custom sorting array by groups with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

Please your help. I have the input_array with 3 groups of values.

The group order I need is:

```
1st group: Pou
2nd group: Apl
3rd group: Gab
```

This order is already done in input_array, but I want to sort ascending each group.

The script I have so far produces the output given in central column of table below (current output).

```
input_arr = ["Pou-12","Pou-7","Pou-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-4","Gab-1","Gab-2"] 

b=input_arr.sort_by do |s|
  if s =~ /^\d+$/
      [2, $&.to_i]
  else
      [1, s]
  end
end

puts b
```

and the desired sorted output array is shown below too.

---

```
 input array  | current output | desired output array
```

---

```
    Pou-12    |     Apl        |      Pou-1
    Pou-7     |     Gab-1      |      Pou-2
    Pou-4     |     Gab-2      |      Pou-3
    Pou-8     |     Gab-3      |      Pou-4
    Pou-9     |     Gab-4      |      Pou-5
    Pou-11    |     Gab-5      |      Pou-6
    Pou-10    |     Pou-1      |      Pou-7
    Pou-3     |     Pou-10     |      Pou-8
    Pou-2     |     Pou-11     |      Pou-9
    Pou-1     |     Pou-12     |      Pou-10
    Pou-6     |     Pou-2      |      Pou-11
    Pou-5     |     Pou-3      |      Pou-12
    Apl       |     Pou-4      |      Apl
    Gab-3     |     Pou-5      |      Gab-1
    Gab-5     |     Pou-6      |      Gab-2
    Gab-4     |     Pou-7      |      Gab-3
    Gab-1     |     Pou-8      |      Gab-4
    Gab-2     |     Pou-9      |      Gab-5
```

**UPDATE**

Cary's solution with array instead of hash.

```
a = ["Pou-7","Pou-4","Gab-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-1","Pou-12","Gab-2"]
order = [ "Pou", "Apl", "Gab" ]

a.map{ |s| head,tail = s.split("-"); [order.index(head), tail.to_i, s]}.sort.map(&:last)

=> ["Pou-1", "Pou-2", "Pou-3", "Pou-4", "Pou-5", "Pou-6", "Pou-7", "Pou-8", "Pou-9", 
"Pou-10", "Pou-11", "Pou-12", "Apl", "Gab-1", "Gab-2", "Gab-3", "Gab-4", "Gab-5"]
```

Comment: Ger, it's the practice on SO to keep questions and answers separate, and in the case of questions, to not modify them once posted except when corrections or clarification is required. It's not relevant here, but askers sometimes post their own answers, and when they do it's as an answer, not a modification of the question.

Comment: Thanks for share that, but is a practice or rule do that?

Comment: Ger, I don't know if there is a rule about that, but if you look through SO questions that have been upvoted you will rarely if ever see an addendum that provides an answer. Part of it may simply be to reduce repetition by keeping questions and answers separate. Other readers are invited to provide their take on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ["Pou-12","Pou-7","Pou-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2",
     "Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-4","Gab-1","Gab-2"]

order = { "Pou"=>0, "Apl"=>1, "Gab"=>2 }
a.map do |s|
  head, tail = s.split('-')
  [order[head], tail.to_i, s]
end.sort.map(&:last)
  #=> ["Pou-1", "Pou-2", "Pou-3", "Pou-4", "Pou-5", "Pou-6", "Pou-7", "Pou-8", "Pou-9",
  #    "Pou-10", "Pou-11", "Pou-12", "Apl, "Gab-1", "Gab-2", "Gab-3", "Gab-4", "Gab-5"]
```

Note that `head, tail = "Apl".split('-') #=> ["Apl"]`, so `head #=> "Apl"` and `tail #=> nil`, but then `tail.to_i #=> nil.to_i #=> 0`.

See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) to understand how arrays are compared when sorting.

Comment: Excellent Cary. It works son fine, printing correct order even if  the input array is not  ordered by groups. Thanks so much

Comment: Thank you Cary for the link of arrays. I've updated my original question showing your solution using "order" array instead of hash. I've learned a lot testing deeper solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
input = ["Pou-12","Pou-7","Pou-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-4","Gab-1","Gab-2"]      

grouped_by_prefix = input.group_by do |item| 
  item.split('-')[0] 
end

grouped_by_prefix.each do |_, values| 
  values.sort_by! { |value| value.split('-')[1].to_i } 
end

['Pou', 'Apl', 'Gab'].reduce([]) do |memo, key| 
  memo + (grouped_by_prefix[key] || []) 
end
```

algorithm is not super efficient (for example double `split` operation) but quite simple to understand

Comment: Hi djaszczurowski, many thanks. I´ve tried your solution too and it works fine either. Excellent. I´ll test with actual data. Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
b = input_arr.group_by { |e| e.split("-")[0] }
b = b.flat_map { |k, v| v.sort_by!{ |vs| vs.split("-")[1].to_i }; v }
```

Comment: Hi Ho man, many thanks.Excellent. It seems to work with this sample. I´ll test with actual data.

Comment: Use `b.flat_map` instead of `b.map { ... }.flatten`.

Comment: Hello Ho Man. Thanks for your help. It works very nice. The only issue I see is when the input array is in different order the output is not sorted by the rule "Pou, Apl, Gab". For example use the follow input array a = ["Pou-7","Pou-4","Gab-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","‌​Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-‌​1","Pou-6","Pou-5","‌​Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5"‌​,"Gab-1","Pou-12","G‌​ab-2"]

Answer (score 1):

Your initial array looks like:

```
a = ["Pou-12","Pou-7","Pou-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-4","Gab-1","Gab-2"]

d = []
```

Group the array by it's first part:

```
c = a.group_by{|b| b.split("-").first}
#=> {"Pou"=>["Pou-12", "Pou-7", "Pou-4", "Pou-8", "Pou-9", "Pou-11",
#=>          "Pou-10", "Pou-3", "Pou-2", "Pou-1", "Pou-6", "Pou-5"],
#=>  "Apl"=>["Apl"],
#=>  "Gab"=>["Gab-3", "Gab-5", "Gab-4", "Gab-1", "Gab-2"]
#=> }
```

Now, sort the grouped array individually:

```
c.each do |k, v|
  d << v.sort{|b, c| ( b.split("-").last.to_i <=> c.split("-").last.to_i )}
end
```

Finally, since the output is Array of Array, you flatten it:

```
d.flatten!

#=> ["Pou-1", "Pou-2", "Pou-3", "Pou-4", "Pou-5", "Pou-6", "Pou-7", "Pou-8", "Pou-9", "Pou-10", "Pou-11", "Pou-12", "Apl", "Gab-1", "Gab-2", "Gab-3", "Gab-4", "Gab-5"]
```

Comment: You abuse `Enumerable#each`, use `d = c.flat_map { ... }`.

Comment: Hello Abhi. Thanks for your help. It works very nice. The only issue I see is when the input array is in different order the output is not sorted by the rule "Pou, Apl, Gab". For example use the follow input array a = ["Pou-7","Pou-4","Gab-4","Pou-8","Pou-9","Pou-11","Pou-10","Pou-3","Pou-2","Pou-1","Pou-6","Pou-5","Apl","Gab-3","Gab-5","Gab-1","Pou-12","Gab-2"]